# Prior six months of data per unique user from an imputed date - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to obtain the last six (6) months of data for unique users in a dataset based on another date (represented by a flag, and will be called the index date).

The "index date" is essentially a flag captured in the data. 1 being the flag is present, 0 meaning it is not.

So if User 1 had a flag (index date) presented on July 1 2020 - I would want their history 6 months prior to July 1 2020 (so all the way to January 1 2020) and whatever is present in their data during that timeframe.

**EXAMPLE DATA TABLE:**

| User | Date | Flag (Index Date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 10-01-2019 | 0 |
| User 1 | 12-15-2019 | 0 |
| User 1 | 12-21-20219 | 0 |
| User 1 | 03-01-2020 | 0 |
| User 1 | 05-15-2020 | 0 |
| User 1 | 07-01-2020 | 1 |
| User 1 | 07-15-2020 | 0 |
| User 1 | 08-01-2020 | 0 |

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT:**

| User | Date | Flag (Index Date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 03-01-2020 | NULL |
| User 1 | 05-15-2020 | NULL |
| User 1 | 07-01-2020 | 1 |
| User 2 | 02-24-2020 | NULL |
| User 2 | 03-12-2020 | NULL |
| User 2 | 04-28-2020 | 1 |

Comment: Edit the question and provide the base table structure also

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I don't understand.

Comment: You have just given the output you want. to help you we need your input table structure and sample data with logic explanation.

Comment: Revised a bit further.

Comment: flag will tell the index date?

Comment: Yes, represented with either 1 or 0 (1 being that the flag is present, 0 meaning it is not present)

Comment: Hope this has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
with cte as 
(select user_,date_ from test where flag=1
)
select 
t.*,
case when t.flag=1 then t.date_ end "Flag (Index Date)"
from test t 
inner join cte on t.user_=cte.user_ 
where t.date_ between cte.date_ - interval '6 month' and cte.date_
order by user_,date_
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=aacc8b7de0fed6fcba001d88227a01de)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without cte as well:

```
select  *
from  test t1
where exists (
        select 1 from test t2
        where t2.flag = 1
            and t1.user = t2.user
            and t1.date between t2.date - interval '6 month' and t2.date
    )
order by  user, date
```

it's assumed you only have only one flag = 1 per user in your data